# Ошибка ORA-01008: не все переменные привязаны

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, oledb

Есть проблема с выполнением параметризованного запроса в c#. Вот мой код:

```
Data = new DataTable("Data098");
OleDbConnection con = connmgr.ORACLE_ORACLE();
cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = @"select sum (round ( (t1.width * t1.thickness * t1.qnt_length * 7.85 * power (10, -9)), 3)) weight
                    from (  select sp.batch_pps_id
                                    , min (sm.s_tickness) keep (dense_rank first order by sp.pstng_date) thickness
                                    , min (sm.s_width) keep (dense_rank first order by sp.pstng_date) width
                                    , min (sp.entry_qnt) keep (dense_rank first order by sp.pstng_date) qnt_length
                                    , min (sp.pstng_date) pstng_date
                            from oracle.z_stan_prod_sap sp, oracle.z_spr_materials sm
                            where sp.stge_loc = '5600'
                                and sp.material = sm.matnr
                                and sm.d_ntdqm = 'ТС 05757848-98-2014'
                            group by sp.batch_pps_id) t1
                    where t1.pstng_date between :start_date and :finish_date";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("start_date", start_date);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("finish_date", end_date);
OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
oda.Fill(Data);
ad.Dispose();
cmd.Dispose();
```

Cmd до этого уже используется в этом блоке но она диспозиться. Проблема в том что на строчке заполнения даты вылетает ошибка.

> ORA-01008: не все переменные привязаны

Что я делаю не так? Может уже взгляд замылился но не как не могу понять.

Comment: Вы пробовали на других запросах с параметрами? Если проблема именно с передачей параметров, то запрос можно заменить на упрощенный и сократить пример. P.S. Почему OleDb, а не ODP?

Comment: Попробуйте убрать привязку дат - и посмотреть, выполнится ли запрос. Также попробуйте создать новый `cmd`. Возможно, от предыдущего использования он не очистился.

Comment: Укажите какие значения принимают `start_date` и `end_date`. Попробуйте упростить запрос и создать [воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `:start_date and :finish_date`, нужно заменить на знаки вопроса `?`, и тогда параметр успешно передаётся.

Comment: Мда... `OleDb` же... Ужос.